# How to define basePath in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

Reviewing the swagger documentation specifically the annotations I did not find how to define the host and basePath properties.
Any idea where to set them?

**documentation consulted:**
[Swagger-2.X---Annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#extensions-annotations)

**Here is a json generated with the variables:**
[petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)

Comment: Which language/framework are you using - Springfox, Swashbuckle, etc.?

Comment: I am using java without any framework,

Comment: The @OpenAPIDefinition annotation, which is the most general, does not contain the host or basePath properties

Answer (score 6):

Swagger 2.x supports **OpenAPI Specification 3.0** (see [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) for reference), where *host*, *basePath* and *schemes* keywords have been replaced by the *server* element.

In OpenAPI 3.0, you can use an array of *server* elements to specify one or more base URLs for your API.

A server URL has the following structure:

```
    scheme://host[:port][/basePath]
```

You can register the servers using the annotation [@Server](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#server):

- in [@OpenAPIDefinition](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#OpenAPIDefinition) (for all operations)
- in [@Operation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#operation) (for a single operation)

Alternatively you can define the servers in your [Swagger configuration file](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) e.g:

**YAML**

```
servers:
- url: https://api.example.com/v1
  description: example
```

**JSON**

```
  "servers" : [ {
    "url" : "https://api.example.com/v1",
    "description" : "example"
  } ]
```