# Spring Boot Swagger through Nginx does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, nginx, swagger

I have configured two services running in separate containers through nginx. Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /template-order-service/ {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://template-order-service:8082/;
    }

    location /template-product-service/ {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://template-product-service:8083/;
    }

}
```

I am able to call both services as exptected, using:

```
http://localhost/template-order-service/<endpoint>
http://localhost/template-product-service/<endpoint>
```

However when I am trying to reach swagger i am getting

> Failed to load remote configuration.

In debugger console I see error like this:

> http://localhost/v3/api-docs/swagger-config 404 Not Found

I am sure that this url should be:

```
http://localhost/template-order-service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

or

```
http://localhost/template-product-service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

How can I fix that in swagger ? In .js file I see some `configUrl` variable but I don't know how to overwrite it. Simple query param (`?configUrl=/template-order-service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`) does not work.

Comment: You need to define the base URL in the Swagger configurations like so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321450/how-to-define-basepath-in-swagger-2-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `X-Forwarded-` headers should help you.
Namely `X-Forwarded-Prefix` to set context path for swagger-ui.

Try this nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /template-order-service/ {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix '/template-order-service';

        proxy_pass http://template-order-service:8082/;
    }

    location /template-product-service/ {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix '/template-product-service';

        proxy_pass http://template-product-service:8083/;
    }

}
```

You might also need to set property for spring boot app: server.forward-headers-strategy=framework

After that you should be able to open swagger-ui at http://localhost(or where your nginx is)/template-order-service/swagger-ui/index.html and
http://localhost/template-product-service//swagger-ui/index.html

You can check more documentation and other headers to modify URL here:
https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: It works (server.forward-headers-strategy was also required). Thank you very much. You help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try yo to update the Swagger UI configuration in your `index.html` file to use the reverse proxy setup:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://localhost/v3/api-docs", // Update this to your desired URL
  dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
    SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
  ],
  layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})
```

Update the `url` property to the correct API documentation URL based on your reverse proxy configuration. For example, if you want to load the API documentation for the `template-order-service`, set the `url` property:

```
url: "http://localhost/template-order-service/v3/api-docs",
```

Similarly, for the `template-product-service`, set the `url` property like this:

```
url: "http://localhost/template-product-service/v3/api-docs",
```

Save the changes and reload the Swagger UI page. The API documentation should now be loaded correctly for the respective services.

If you want to have both services available in the same Swagger UI, you might consider using a dropdown or a selection option to switch between different API documentation URLs. Then, update the `url` property based on the selected service.